# Is it possible to draw a Drawable and get a bitmap from it?

Tags: c++, sfml

Is it possible to get a drawn `Drawable` as a `Texture` (a bitmap)? How could I do that, please?

---

**My try**

I've modified the green circle example. Now it's really drawn as a bitmap...

But it's drawn just like that:

[image: Unsmooth Arc.]

I'd like to have **anti-aliasing**.

With the `RenderWindow` class I was able to put the anti-aliasing, by passing a `ContextSettings`. Using @Mario's suggestion I need `RenderTexture`, and I don't have control over its `ContextSettings`, unfortunately.

**@AlexG's suggestion**

I've created a `Context`, but my compiler says `my_test.cc:9:57: error: use of deleted function 'sf::Context::Context(const sf::Context&)'`. Err! Any alternative?

```
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>
#include <SFML/Window.hpp>

int main()
{
    sf::ContextSettings settings =
        sf::ContextSettings(0, 0, 6);

    sf::Context context = sf::Context(settings, 200, 200);
    context.setActive(true);

    sf::RenderWindow window(
        sf::VideoMode(200, 200), "sfml test", sf::Style::Default,
        settings
    );

    sf::RenderTexture cacheTexture;
    if (!cacheTexture.create(200, 200)) return 0;
    cacheTexture.setSmooth(true);

    sf::CircleShape shape(100.f, 75);
    shape.setFillColor(sf::Color::Green);

    cacheTexture.setActive(true);
    cacheTexture.draw(shape);

    cacheTexture.setActive(false);
    context.setActive(false);

    sf::Sprite sprite = sf::Sprite(cacheTexture.getTexture());

    while (window.isOpen())
    {
        sf::Event event;

        while (window.pollEvent(event))
        {
            if (event.type == sf::Event::Closed)
                window.close();
        }

        window.clear();
        window.draw(sprite);
        window.display();
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You can draw the shape to an `sf::RenderTexture` just like @Mario says. If you pass your context settings to a `sf::Context` you can set the antialiasing level just as you did the window (as long as the `sf::RenderTexture` is the current context).

Hope that helps!

Comment: There's no way to link a `Context` to the `RenderTexture` :(

Comment: Not explicitly, no. But calling `setActive()` on the  `sf::RenderTexture` will make it the current context.

Comment: I cannot construct `Context` for some reason.

Comment: If I refer you to the [https://www.sfml-dev.org/documentation/2.4.2/classsf_1_1Context.php](docs) you should see that you can use a static method to fetch the current context. What I would suggest is grabbing the context after calling `setActive()` on the rendertex, then calling `getSettings()` to fetch a reference to that context's settings and modifying them there.

Comment: Nice idea... I've tried compiling after these suggestions, but I can't modify the `ContextSettings#antialiasingLevel` member because it's read-only, so the compiler stops here. Do you have any ideas on that case? It's super limited :v That looks proposital, for serious.

Comment: I can't really see from the docs any other path unfortunately. I don't have anything installed atm so I can't offer any practical assistance unfortunately. Is there a possibility of constructing another `ContextSettings` object and swapping them out? If it's a reference you might be able to swap the data at the pointer.

Comment: <u>Hummm, it may be dangerous :V because `ContextSettings` may be stored in different forms...</u> Well, that's true. I could replace the value at the pointer. Truly, I can't... well, very confused

Comment: Thanks for your  help. I think @binary1248 has solved the issue... https://github.com/SFML/SFML/pull/1285#issuecomment-330708937

Answer (score 2):

It's pretty trivial to do. Just draw your drawable to a `sf::RenderTexture` of the desired size and you can use `sf::RenderTexture::getTexture()` to get a texture you can use or save to a file.